# The NullPointerException crash that occur in the flutter under RenderMode of rendermode.texture

Tags: flutter, nullpointerexception, textures

> Crashes occur with the latest stable version 1.17.0，the log is :
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.RenderSurface.attachToRenderer(io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.FlutterRenderer)' on a null object reference.

tips:
RenderMode.surface is normal,and rendermode.texture is bad.

the code as:

```
FlutterFragment flutterFragment = FlutterFragment.withCachedEngine("my_engine_id")
    .renderMode(FlutterView.RenderMode.texture)
    .build();
```